# Jquery - "hasClass()" doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Heei, I've code like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
    <a href="#!">Click</a>
    <ul class="overlay_modal">
        /*some LI element*/
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.overlay_modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("div.card > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next().addClass("active");
});

if ($(".overlay_modal").hasClass("active")) {
    $("body").css({
        "height" : "100vh",
        "overflow" : "hidden"
    });
}
else {
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Result

[image]

as you can see, the `body` background still red when `.overlay_modal` hass class `active`. What's wrong with my code, please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an active class to your ul element like so:

```
<ul class="option__list active">
```

The jquery expression that you have would negate because there is no .active class in the first place.

Edit:

```
$("div.card .option > a").click(function() {
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
    if ($(".card .option ul").hasClass("active")) {
        $("body").css({
            "height" : "100vh",
            "overflow" : "hidden"
        });
    }
    else {
        $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've edit my question for better explain my problem, please check :)

Comment: The onclick event does not fire so your code will execute the if-block first. It will not see any .active class unless the onclick event is fired first before the if-block. I've edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, it's not work in my case. Let I give a screenshot and may you can know what I mean :)